# Animate Background Color from/to Transparent

Tags: javascript, css

I'd like to make the background color of some text fade-in/out on hover. Since the text is on top of an image, I'd like the background color to fade in from transparency then back to transparent.

This is what I have so far:

```
    $('#nav li.menu').hover(
    function () {
        $(this).animate({backgroundColor: "#FFEF00"},300);

    }, 
    function () {
        $("li.menu").animate({backgroundColor: "Transparent"},300);         
    }
);
```

However, when I run this code, the animation turns the background color to white before beginning to animate. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Thanks,
MJ

Comment: Have you included [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/animate/) ?

Comment: It would be greatly appreciated if http://jsfiddle.net/ was used in the answer. I'm still learning javascript so a working demo would be really helpful!

Comment: Yes I have included jQuery UI

Answer (score 0):

All animated properties should be animated to a single numeric value,most properties that are non-numeric cannot be animated using basic jQuery functionality (For example, width, height, or left can be animated but background-color cannot be, unless the [jQuery.Color()](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color) plugin is used). Property values are treated as a number of pixels unless otherwise specified. The units em and % can be specified where applicable.

for more information check this out

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

http://desizntech.info/2009/06/playing-with-jquery-color-plugin-and-color-animation/

Answer (score 0):

"transparent" by itself doesn't mean much. A colour is defined by red, green, blue and alpha. Since the default background colour for a page is white, it makes sense that "transparent" is actually translated as "white with alpha 0".

Try using `rgba()` notation to force a specific "transparent" colour.

```
$("li.menu").animate({backgroundColor:"rgba(0xff,0xef,0,0)"});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can indeed not change background colors easily through jquery as afshin says.
however, there is another way!
Put the text in a div, and give the div the same color as the background. (or whatever color it should be)

Then, make another class or id in your css, and use jquery to change the class/id on hover. (`.getElement` command, if you need to know)

best of luck.